# Send Flow API giving Unsupported post request

Tags: whatsapp-cloud-api, whatsapp-flows

[image: Error messsage]

[image: Flow created]

I'm trying to send a flow but I'm always getting that the object id doesn't esxist (the phone number).

`curl --location 'https://graph.facebook.com/v18.0/5731.../messages' \ --header 'Authorization: Bearer EAA...' \ --header 'Content-Type: application/json' \ --data '{ "recipient_type": "individual", "messaging_product": "whatsapp", "to": "5841..", "type": "interactive", "interactive": { "type": "flow", "header": { "type": "text", "text": "Flow message header" }, "body": { "text": "Flow message body" }, "footer": { "text": "Flow message footer" }, "action": { "name": "flow", "parameters": { "flow_message_version": "3", "flow_token": "AQAAAAACS5FpgQ_cAAAAAD0QI3s.", "flow_id": "1211462153575982", "flow_cta": "Book!", "flow_action": "data_exchange" } } } }'`

Any guess what i'm doing wrong?

Send the flow........................................

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### 1. Verify permissions

This looks like a permission error, it seems the account you used to generate the token does not have permission to this number `5731...`. You can check your permissions here (replace waba & business id)

[https://business.facebook.com/settings/whatsapp-business-accounts/{waba-id}?business_id={business-id}](https://business.facebook.com/settings/whatsapp-business-accounts/%7Bwaba-id%7D?business_id=%7Bbusiness-id%7D)

To create and send flows you need these permissions "Message templates (view and manage)" & "Phone Numbers (view and manage)"

#### 2. Verify the request

The field `"flow_action": "data_exchange"` should only be used if your flow uses an endpoint. If you flow doesn't have and endpoint then the action and payload should be like this

```
"flow_action": "navigate",
"flow_action_payload": {
    "screen": "<YOUR_SCREEN>",
    "data": {
        "<CUSTOM_KEY>": "<CUSTOM_VALUE>"
    }
}
```

You can also check the example request in the [postman collection here](https://www.postman.com/meta/workspace/whatsapp-business-platform/documentation/24926895-7bf51205-92ed-49d1-af4a-0130cf84b6f6?entity=request-cea2e676-895a-4f5b-a431-ef59e3019836)